# Postgres Select Where JSON Field Not Null

Tags: json, postgresql, select

I have a table which has a column called warnings. the column value for 2 rows is shown bellow

```
                             warnings
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"isNew":false,"fieldWarnings":[],"dupId":null,"conflictIds":[]}
 {"isNew":false,"fieldWarnings":[],"dupId":3763,"conflictId":null}
```

I want an sql statement that will select the top row but not the bottom row. i tried this sql query but it selects both rows

```
select warnings from table where cast(warnings->>'dubId' AS TEXT) is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `dubId` in your query but the JSON property is `dupId`. I think you've just got a typo!

Try this instead:

```
select warnings from table where cast(warnings->>'dupId' AS TEXT) is null;
```

Also, the `->>` operator returns the field value as text already so you shouldn't need the cast:

```
select warnings from table where warnings->>'dupId' is null;
```